# What does it mean in the attached picture?

Tags: functions

[image]

Simply in english below the door bell:

Attention:
x - doorbell
f(x) - how the door bell works.

But what exactly it is in math. I do not know such syntax. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally, "not there exists x such that it works as a doorbell".

In other words, "The doorbell doesn't work, no matter what you try."

Comment: why you think it doesnt work?

Comment: What is "3" and "~"?

Comment: The "3" is really a backwards E and it means "there exists."  The ~ means "not".

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk [list of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)   $\exists$ means there does exist.  $\neg$ means the negation of a logical sentence.  $\exists x~f(x)$ means that there exists an $x$ such that $f(x)$ is true.  $\neg(\exists x~f(x))$ means that the sentence that there exists an $x$ such that $f(x)$ is true is false, i.e. all doorbells don't work.